# how to create EditText more than one line in android

Tags: android

i am having a hard time creating a EditText which is multiline and width of nearly "100dp".
The functionality is what i want that one can enter his short message of 10-20 lines in it, just like i am typing my question in this BOX.Here is the code i am using to get the desired functionality.

```
<EditText android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:text="" 
    android:layout_height="100dp" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/desc_text" 
    android:layout_marginLeft = "5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight = "5dp"
    android:scrollHorizontally ="true"
    android:scrollbars = "vertical"
    android:singleLine = "false">
</EditText>
```

but i am getting a edit text of 100dp height but still taking single line input from middle.
Please help me how to do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try below code

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/msgtext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:layout_height="150dip"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:padding="5dip">
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `android:gravity="top"` to your EditText object

Answer (score 3):

Add this attribute `android:lines="3"` to your xml  to have a TextView with 3 lines.

Answer (score 3):

Set this property in your xml file `android:maxLines=" 20"` 20 lines edittext is this.

Answer (score 2):

in Java:

```
  input = findViewById(R.id.desc_text);
    input.setMinLines(3);
```

or in XML:

```
android:minLines="5"
```